# "@Transactional(readonly=true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)" Is it possible to set it up?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, nested, replication, propagation

Currently, I am using the postgresql master/slave environment.
The development environment is spring boot.

I'd like to organize the transaction as follows:

```
TX Begin 
   @Transactional (readOnly=false)
      insert into t1 values(1);
      
   @Transactional (readOnly=true, propagation=Propagation.NESTED) or 
   @Transactional (readOnly=true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
      select * from t1 where c1=1; 
      
   commit;
TX End;
```

In the above case, is it possible to read the records from the Replica (Slave) server without having to commit after INSERT?

Thanks.